# PXE Boot Server Installation Steps in Ubuntu Server VM

Tags: system-installation, software-installation, virtualization, pxe

How can I install Ubuntu virtual machine using PXE boot server?

I need the all the configurations details and what to change in the configurations files.

Answer (score 31):

### PXE (Preboot eXecution Environment, pronounced pixie)‬

See [Wikipedia: PXE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preboot_Execution_Environment)

### How it works?

*This is my understanding!*

[image: PXE_Diagram_en.png]

1. Client machine is powered on. BIOS scans for devices. Then it follows by trying to load boot-loader from required device as listed in *Boot Order/Sequence*. It loads PXE from network card ROM.
2. PXE (client side) broadcast a request for an IP. DHCP server reply with the required information: IP, Next Server IP (TFTP server IP), `pxelinux.0` (PXE bootstrap loader file name), ...etc

   [image: PXE_Boot_1.png]
3. PXE (client side) requests `pxelinux.0` file from TFTP server, loads it to RAM then passes control to `pxelinux.0`.

   `pxelinux.0` gets boot configuration file from TFTP server with name as:
   (if it doesn't exist it tries with the next)

   - UUID
   - MAC
   - IP in Capital Hex
   - A portion of the IP
   - Drops to `default` file

   [image: PXE_Boot_2.png]
4. Either user choice or default menu entry. `pxelinux.0` requests the corresponding kernel and RAMDisk from the TFTP server and loads them to RAM.

   Then passes boot parameters and control to the loaded kernel.

   [image: PXE_Linux.png]
5. Kernel loads the remaining parts from TFTP server or any other protocol server depending its features/properties.

   [image: Parted_Magic_1.png]
   [image: Parted_Magic_2.png]

### Server Setup

There are many ways to setup PXE server, this is one of them.

These instructions were tested on *Ubuntu 9.10* & *Ubuntu 10.04* on a real machine. They should be still valid with only few changes may be. (Updated & Tested for Ubuntu 14.04 on VirtualBox , check edit revisions for old releases)

My target was *PartedMagic 4.5*, it should be similar to Ubuntu or any Linux distribution.

1. Install DHCP & TFTP packages

   ```
       sudo apt-get install isc-dhcp-server openbsd-inetd lftp tftpd-hpa syslinux
   ```
2. DHCP Setup

   - Edit `/etc/default/isc-dhcp-server`, Ethernet interface for DHCP service

     ```
     INTERFACES="eth0"
     ```
   - Edit `/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf‬` or `/etc/ltsp/dhcpd.conf` it does exist, DHCP service configuration

     PXE specific configurations: `filename` & `next-server`

     ```
     default-lease-time 600;
     max-lease-time 7200;
     subnet 192.168.10.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
         range 192.168.10.50 192.168.10.100;
         option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
         option routers 192.168.10.123;
         option broadcast-address 192.168.10.255;
         filename "pxelinux.0";
         next-server 192.168.10.123;
     }
     ```
   - Setup a static IP for `eth0`, `192.168.10.123` in my case using network manager for Desktop edition or `/etc/network/interfaces` for Server edition.

     ```
     auto eth0
     iface eth0 inet static
     address 192.168.10.123
     netmask 255.255.255.0
     network 192.168.10.0
     broadcast 192.168.10.255
     ```

     Reinitialize the network interface:

     ```
     sudo ifdown eth0
     sudo ifup eth0
     ```
   - Re-start service

     ```
     sudo service isc-dhcp-server restart
     ```

     Check status

     ```
     netstat -lu
     ```

     Output

     ```
     Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
     udp        0      0 *:bootpc                *:*
     ```
3. TFTP Setup

   - Edit `‪/etc/inetd.conf`, remove `#<off>#` from the beginning of `tftp` line or add if it not there under `#:BOOT:` comment. (Skip this with systemd, 15.10 and later)

     ```
     tftp    dgram   udp wait    root    /usr/sbin/in.tftpd  /usr/sbin/in.tftpd -s /var/lib/tftpboot
     ```
   - Enable boot service for `inetd`

     ```
     sudo update-inetd --enable BOOT
     ```
   - Start service

     ```
     sudo service openbsd-inetd restart
     sudo service tftpd-hpa restart
     ```

     Check status

     ```
     netstat -lu
     ```

     Output

     ```
     Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State 
     udp        0      0 *:tftp                  *:*
     ```
4. PXE boot files setup

   - Unzip `pmagic-pxe-4.5.zip`. If `pxelinux.0` is not there, get it from `sysliux-common` package installed at `/usr/lib/syslinux/pxelinux.0`, [Syslinux Project](http://www.syslinux.org/) or [Ubuntu Netboot Image](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/netboot/).

     Put them in similar structure.

     ```
     /var/lib/tftpboot/
      |-- pxelinux.0
      |-- pxelinux.cfg/
      |   `-- default
      `-- pmagic/
          |-- bzimage
          `-- initramfs
     ```
   - Edit `/var/lib/tftpboot/pxelinux.cfg/default`, if needed example paths: `pmagic/bzimage` & `pmagic/initramfs`

     ```
     DEFAULT partmagic 

     LABEL partmagic 
         MENU LABEL PartMagic 4.5 
         KERNEL pmagic/bzimage 
         APPEND initrd=pmagic/initramfs edd=off noapic load_ramdisk=1 prompt_ramdisk=0 rw vga=791 sleep=10 loglevel=0 keymap=us livemedia
     ```
   - Setup correct permissions

     ```
     sudo find /var/lib/tftpboot -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
     sudo find /var/lib/tftpboot -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
     ```

### Client Setup

Change BIOS boot order for one time using <kbd>F9</kbd> or <kbd>F12</kbd>,
for permanent setup from BIOS configuration <kbd>DEL</kbd>,<kbd>F2</kbd> or <kbd>F12</kbd>. (Depending on machine brand)

Move to the top: `[PXE | NIC | LAN | Ethernet | Network]`.

### Notes

- `inetutils-inetd` or `xinetd` can be used instead of `openbsd-inetd`, some `inetd` steps are different.
- TFTP root directory could be change from `/etc/default/tftpd-hpa`. Remember to update `‪/etc/inetd.conf` too.
- Many distribution support loading RAMDisk through many protocols: SSH(SFTP), SMB, NFS ... Example Ubuntu support NFS.
- Some old network cards do not support PXE, [iPXE](http://ipxe.org/) ([Ex. gPXE or Etherboot](http://etherboot.org/)) can be used, either on floppy disk, USB drive, Harddisk (`/boot` partition) or even flash it to ROM (only few NIC supported). GRUB2 has module to support booting using PXE.

  See also [Wikipedia: gPXE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPXE) and [ROM-O-matic](http://rom-o-matic.net/).
- Ubuntu Netboot Image from [cdimage.ubuntu.com/netboot/](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/netboot/)  provides installing Ubuntu from network and it will ask to download all required packages from the official mirror or a local one if you have one.

  Most users are looking for booting live image through PXE. This question was only to setup a PXE server. See [Ubuntu Wiki: Installation - LocalNet](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/LocalNet)

  [image: Ubuntu NetBoot - Official archive mirror]
  [image: Ubuntu NetBoot - Custom/Local archive mirror]
- PXE Menu can be customized, best template to learn from is [Ubuntu NetBoot](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/netboot/). See [Pxeboot Multiple image](https://askubuntu.com/questions/427053/pxeboot-multiple-image/)

  [image: PXE_Linux_Menu.png]
- `memdisk` can be used to load directly the ISO or floppy disk images through PXE. `syslinux-common` package has a copy. Client should have enough RAM to hold the image plus a portion for running the loaded OS.

  Configuration example:

  ```
  /var/lib/tftpboot/
  |-- FDSTD.144
  |-- memdisk
  |-- pxelinux.0
  |-- slitaz-cooking.iso
  |-- pxelinux.cfg
  |   `-- default
  `-- pmagic/
      |-- bzimage
      `-- initramfs
  ```

  `/pxelinux.cfg/default`

  ```
  DEFAULT partmagic

  LABEL partmagic
      MENU LABEL PartMagic 4.5
      KERNEL pmagic/bzimage
      APPEND initrd=pmagic/initramfs edd=off noapic load_ramdisk=1 prompt_ramdisk=0 rw vga=791 sleep=10 loglevel=0 keymap=us livemedia

  LABEL slitaz
      MENU LABEL ^Slitaz.iso
      TEXT HELP
  Testing boot from iso.
      ENDTEXT 
      KERNEL memdisk
      APPEND initrd=slitaz-cooking.iso

  LABEL freedos_std
      MENU LABEL ^FreeDOS STD
      TEXT HELP
  Testing boot from Floppy IMG.
      ENDTEXT 
      KERNEL memdisk
      APPEND initrd=FDSTD.144
  ```
- PartedMagic packages were dropped from the official site after original developer decided to make it commercial, some releases could be found through torrent network. My answer here is a resume of first PXE setup that worked for me. [Ubuntu Netboot Image](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/netboot/) should work with same instructions.

Comment: Friends, Actually i am working on Pxeboot.

I installed these packages in one virtual machine(Oracle Virtualbox),
apt-get install nfs-kernel-server
apt-get install tftpd-hpa inetutils-inetd
apt-get install syslinux
apt-get install isc-dhcp-server

I edit the dhcpd.conf file and got the dhcp server running

Comment: @Sneetsher : Hi, I am using tftpd-hda, configured with default values. A `netstat -lu | grep tftp` shows it in listening mode. The /tftpboot folder is 777, however if I try to `tftp> get pxelinux.0` it from the client I get always a *tftp: pxelinux.0: Permission denied* error. Do you have an idea to debug it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Danduk82, `/var/lib/tftpboot/` with 755 (default) should be ok. Check if `pxelinux.0` have 644 or run `sudo chmod -R +r /var/lib/tftpboot/` to make all its contents readable.

Comment: @raju, I didn't get what you are pointing to. Did you find any specific problem the setup?

Comment: Hi, actually I have solved the problem: In fact I (stupidely) forgot to restart the DHCP service after adding `filename "pxelinux.0";` ... no comment ;P ... thanks for your answer and for this great (and complete) answer. Cheers

Comment: Where do you find the `pmagic-pxe-xxx.zip`?

Comment: @Matthieu, You may find some releases through torrent network, the packages were dropped from the official site after original developer decided to make it commercial. Also you may use http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/netboot/ if you are looking just to test or setup PXE for first time.

Comment: @user.dz thanks, I saw you had to buy it, I thought there was a free alternative in the `apt`. Now I can boot on PXE.