# Pxeboot Multiple image

Tags: boot, pxe

How to do the multiple OS in a single Pxeboot server.

I want to boot different OS like Fedora, CentOS, RHEL in the client

Answer (score 2):

I thought it is good to mention the whole setup I have which may contain interesting tricks.

- It is possible to make separate directories within tftp root folder:

  ```
  $ tree -L 2
  .
  ├── anax_bios_flash.img
  ├── clonezilla_20100623
  │   ├── filesystem.squashfs
  │   ├── initrd.img
  │   ├── parameters.txt
  │   └── vmlinuz
  ├── display_ubuntu
  │   ├── adtext.cfg
  │   ├── f10.txt
  │   ├── f1.txt
  │   ├── f2.txt
  │   ├── f3.txt
  │   ├── f4.txt
  │   ├── f5.txt
  │   ├── f6.txt
  │   ├── f7.txt
  │   ├── f8.txt
  │   ├── f9.txt
  │   ├── menu.cfg
  │   ├── po4a.cfg
  │   ├── prompt.cfg
  │   ├── splash0.png
  │   ├── splash1.png
  │   ├── splash.png
  │   ├── splash.xcf
  │   ├── stdmenu.cfg
  │   ├── text.cfg
  │   └── vesamenu.c32
  ├── etc
  │   └── boot.conf
  ├── FDSTD.144
  ├── hello.boot
  ├── memdisk
  ├── Notes.txt
  ├── openbsd_3.9
  │   ├── bsd
  │   ├── bsd.mp
  │   ├── bsd.rd
  │   └── pxeboot.0
  ├── ploplinux_4.0.0
  │   ├── boot.msg
  │   ├── bzimage
  │   ├── initrfs.gz
  │   ├── memtest
  │   ├── ploplinux
  │   ├── plpbt.bin
  │   ├── plpinstc.com
  │   ├── pluspacks
  │   ├── pxelinux.0
  │   ├── pxelinux.cfg
  │   └── readme.txt
  ├── pmagic_5.5
  │   ├── boot
  │   ├── bzImage
  │   ├── initramfs
  │   └── sample_pxelinux.cfg
  ├── pmagic_6.7
  │   ├── boot
  │   ├── bzImage
  │   └── initramfs
  ├── pxechain.com
  ├── pxelinux.0
  ├── pxelinux.cfg
  │   ├── default
  │   └── default.backup
  ├── slitaz-cooking.iso
  ├── ubuntu_10.04
  │   ├── initrd.gz
  │   └── vmlinuz
  ├── ubuntu_mini.iso
  └── unattended_4.9
      ├── bzImage
      ├── default
      ├── initrd
      ├── menu.c32
      └── pxelinux.0
  ```
- Then change `pxelinux.cfg/default`, `pxelinux.cfg/CLIENT_MAC` or `pxelinux.cfg/PORTION_OF_CLIENT_IP`

  For me, I used Ubuntu Netboot as template, So as you can see `pxelinux.cfg/default` includes `display_ubuntu/menu.cfg` which by itself includes `display_ubuntu/text.cfg` which contains the main menu of Ubuntu boot:

  **Contents of `pxelinux.cfg/default`**

  ```
  include display_ubuntu/menu.cfg
  default display_ubuntu/vesamenu.c32
  prompt 0
  timeout 0
  ```

  **Contents of `display_ubuntu/menu.cfg`**

  ```
  menu hshift 7
  menu width 65
  menu margin 5

  menu title GNU/Linux Rescue Collection

  include display_ubuntu/stdmenu.cfg
  include display_ubuntu/text.cfg

  menu begin advanced
      menu title Advanced options
      label mainmenu
          menu label ^Back..
          menu exit
      include display_ubuntu/stdmenu.cfg
      include display_ubuntu/adtext.cfg
  menu end

  label help
      menu label ^Help
      config display_ubuntu/prompt.cfg
  ```

  **Contents of `display_ubuntu/text.cfg`**

  ```
  DEFAULT partedmagic_6.7

  LABEL test_kernel
      MENU LABEL ^Test Kernel
      KERNEL hello.boot

  LABEL partedmagic_6.7
      LINUX pmagic_6.7/bzImage
      INITRD pmagic_6.7/initramfs
      APPEND edd=off load_ramdisk=1 prompt_ramdisk=0 rw vga=normal loglevel=9 max_loop=256

  LABEL partedmagic_5.5
      MENU LABEL PartedMagic 5.5
      LINUX pmagic_5.5/bzImage
      APPEND initrd=pmagic_5.5/initramfs edd=off noapic load_ramdisk=1 prompt_ramdisk=0 rw vga=791 loglevel=0 max_loop=256

  menu begin pmagic_advanced
          menu title PartedMagic 5.5 Advanced
          label mainmenu
                  menu label ^Back..
                  menu exit
          include /pmagic_5.5/boot/syslinux.cfg
  menu end

  LABEL clonezilla_20100623
      MENU LABEL ^CloneZilla 2010.06.23
      KERNEL clonezilla_20100623/vmlinuz
      APPEND initrd=clonezilla_20100623/initrd.img boot=live union=aufs noswap noprompt vga=788 ocs_live_keymap=NONE ocs_lang=en_US.UTF-8 fetch=tftp://192.168.10.123/clonezilla_20100623/filesystem.squashfs

  LABEL unattended_4.9
      MENU LABEL Unattended 4.9 for ^XP
      KERNEL unattended_4.9/bzImage
      APPEND initrd=unattended_4.9/initrd z_path=\\192.168.10.123\install_4.9

  LABEL slitaz
      MENU LABEL ^Slitaz.iso
      TEXT HELP
  Testing boot from iso.
      ENDTEXT 
      KERNEL memdisk
      APPEND initrd=slitaz-cooking.iso

  LABEL mini_ubutnu
      MENU LABEL Mini-Ubuntu
      KERNEL memdisk
      APPEND initrd=ubuntu_mini.iso

  LABEL freedos_std
      MENU LABEL ^FreeDOS STD
      TEXT HELP
  Testing boot from Floppy IMG.
      ENDTEXT 
      KERNEL memdisk
      APPEND initrd=FDSTD.144

  LABEL anax_bios_flash
      MENU LABEL Anax Bios Flash
      KERNEL memdisk
      APPEND initrd=anax_bios_flash.img

  LABEL openbsd
      MENU LABEL ^OpenBSD 3.9
      KERNEL openbsd_3.9/pxeboot.0

  LABEL plop_4.0.0
      MENU LABEL PlopLinux 4.0.0
      KERNEL ploplinux_4.0.0/bzimage
      APPEND initrd=ploplinux_4.0.0/initrfs.gz vga=1 nfsmount=192.168.10.123:/media/gnu_files/_servers/tftp/ploplinux_4.0.0/ploplinux

  LABEL ubuntu_10.04_install
          menu label ^Ubuntu 10.04 net install
          kernel ubuntu_10.04/vmlinuz
          append vga=normal initrd=ubuntu_10.04/initrd.gz -- quiet

  LABEL ubuntu_10.04_cli
          menu label Ubuntu 10.04 ^command-line net install
          kernel ubuntu_10.04/vmlinuz
          append tasks=standard pkgsel/language-pack-patterns= pkgsel/install-language-support=false vga=normal initrd=ubuntu_10.04/initrd.gz -- quiet

  LABEL pxeserver2
          menu label Switch to 2nd PXE server...
          kernel pxechain.com
          append 192.168.10.254::pxelinux.0
  ```

**Notes:**

- `hello.boot` is a just tiny kernel, I used it for initial PXE tests.
- `memdisk` is used as kernel to load (over PXE):

  **Raw floppy images:** `anax_bios_flash.img` and `FDSTD.144`

  **CD ISO images:** `slitaz-cooking.iso` and `ubuntu_mini.iso`
- `pxechain.com` used to chain load other PXE server.

  `pxechain.com` is available within `syslinux-common` package starting from trusty (Thanks to @muru) or [syslinux project archive](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/boot/syslinux/) under different filename `pxechn.c32`.
- All listed Linux distributions are loaded by same `pxelinux.0` located on tftp root folder. The exception is with OpenBSD (which has BSD kernel), `pxelinux.0` loads `openbsd_3.9/pxeboot.0`, the PXE bootstrap coming with OpenBSD. It has its own configuration at `etc/boot.conf`. (This method is called chain loading)

  **Contents of `etc/boot.conf`**

  ```
  set image openbsd_3.9/bsd
  ```
- You can use `include` instead of listing the whole menu in a single file, or may be chain menus to to keep the original advanced menus/options of each distribution.

Comment: Can we have a menu entry redirect to another server? I have only seen local images listed so far.

Comment: @muru, yes, I didn't look for such thing before. I've update the answer. (Server chaining using `pxechain.com`). Thank you I learned new thing from you.

Comment: Can't say you learned anything from. I just thought to mention it because `pxechain.com`, while available in the `syslinux-common` package of `wheezy` and `trusty`, is not available in that package for `precise`. I hoped you might know of an alternative. Guess I'll upgrade to trusty.

Comment: @muru, No you don't have to upgrade. syslinux is independent  project. You can just download trusty package or upstream package from [syslinux project site](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/boot/syslinux/), Extract it and copy needed files.