# How do I run a PXE server?

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, pxe

I'm going to run several virtual machines with KVM virtualization. In order to install guest systems over PXE protocol, I am going to run a PXE server on my host machine (I'm not doing it wrong, am I?)

How can I do that?

Comment: See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation#Server_and_network_installations , may be this also could be helpful [PXE Boot Server Installation Steps in Ubuntu Server VM](https://askubuntu.com/questions/412574/pxe-boot-server-installation-steps-in-ubuntu-server-vm/414813#414813)

Answer (score 0):

No, you are not wrong. You can even setup PXE server in a virtual machine too.

But I see it just additional work without much benefit, as you can make clones in VM. With VirtualBox for example, it has `--mtype multiattach` option to attach storage media from a base image. Then it will create just an incremental image for changes. See [Multiple VirtualBox VMs using one base image (copy-on-write)](http://www.electricmonk.nl/log/2011/09/24/multiple-virtualbox-vms-using-one-base-image-copy-on-write/)