# how to set set up TFTPD and DHCP for PXE like booot

Tags: networking, server, dhcp, tftp

I am trying to setup tftpd and dhcp to assign IP address to router and then to pass the server and path to kernel image, which will be booted.

All the guides I have located tell me to install and configure tftp and dhcp. I have tried many different dhcp server (isc, dhcp3).

Do I need to install something else like init.d or something like that? Is that even something I can install?

I am using a live cd of 12.04 ubuntu. PLEASE HELP. All the different dhcp's dont help (isc, dhcp3, dhcp) these make it confusing on where to put configuration files for the tftp and dhcp.

Comment: Check http://askubuntu.com/questions/412574/pxe-boot-server-installation-steps-in-ubuntu-server-vm