# Unable to setup a pxe server on Ubuntu VM (Virtual Box)

Tags: 14.04, networking, virtualbox, dhcp, pxe

I am bit new to this and trying to setup PXE server on Ubuntu 14.04 VM using Virtual Box 4.3. For this I have followed following link for my installation:
[PXE Boot Server Installation Steps in Ubuntu Server VM](https://askubuntu.com/questions/412574/pxe-boot-server-installation-steps-in-ubuntu-server-vm/414813#414813)

1. Installed Virtual Box on Mac Yosemite.
2. Deployed Ubuntu VM 14.04 on Virtual box.
3. Installed and configured DHCP server on Ubuntu. 
   Edited `/etc/default/isc-dhcp-server` for `eth0`.

   `dhcp.d` has following configuration

   ```
   default-lease-time 600;
   max-lease-time 7200;
   subnet 192.168.10.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
       range 192.168.10.50 192.168.10.100;
       option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
       option routers 192.168.10.123;
       option broadcast-address 192.168.10.255;
       filename "pxelinux.0";
       next-server 192.168.10.123;
   }
   ```
4. Configured static IP address on Ubuntu VM

   ```
   # interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
   auto lo
   iface lo inet loopback

   auto eth0
   iface eth0 inet static
   address 192.168.10.123
   netmask 255.255.255.0
   network 192.168.10.0
   gateway 192.168.10.2
   dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
   broadcast 192.168.10.255
   ```
5. Setup TFTP service

   ```
   /etc/inetd.conf
   # <service_name> <sock_type> <proto> <flags> <user> <server_path> <args>
   tftp    dgram   udp wait    root    /usr/sbin/in.tftpd  /usr/sbin/in.tftpd -s /var/lib/tftpboot
   ```
6. Added PXE boot files with following structure

   ```
   /var/lib/tftpboot/
    |-- pxelinux.0
    |-- pxelinux.cfg/
    |   `-- default
    `-- pmagic/
        |-- bzimage
        `-- initramfs
   ```
7. On Mac configured `en06` interface with

   ```
   IP Addr: 192.168.10.30
   Router : 192.168.10.1
   DNS Server 8.8.8.8
   ```

made network adapter bridged on virtual box. Disabled WiFi.

8. Host and VM both can ping each other now.
9. Connected Mac with Cat6 Ethernet cable to remote Lenovo machine which I want to PXE boot.
10. When I try to boot Lenovo using PXE as first preference it show error that:

    > no dhcp offer received

Could you help me here to figure out what I am missing? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1G network card may let you connect both laptop using a *direct* cable. But for some 100M network cards and most old ones you have to use a *crossover* cable.

I'm not sure about this, but i have noticed that sometimes  DHCP daemon get killed when network connection drops while reboot/reset of the client machine, I would recommend placing an *Ethernet switch* between the two machines.

If you don't have switch, here what I used to make it works:

1. Power on VM PXE server
2. Power on PXE client machine
3. Wait to get no IP error
4. Restart DHCP service in VM PXE server
5. Try **Reset** PXE client machine multiple times till it gets an IP (don't power off, some brands accept <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> for reset)