# Can I dual boot Ubuntu and windows 7 using bit torrent? Currently can't use usb or CD/DVD drive

Tags: dual-boot

Can I dual boot Ubuntu and windows 7 using bit torrent? Currently can't use usb or CD/DVD drive to boot iso so I'm looking for another way if possible.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean. Do you want to boot from a network source? Please give us more information what you trying to achieve.

Comment: I downloaded Ubuntu 18.04 desktop-amd64.iso using bit torrent. My goal is to use the Ubuntu operating system along side my windows 7 or instead of. Is there a way I can install Ubuntu on my hard drive and boot up Ubuntu instead of Windows 7 and can this be done without the use of a USB drive and or CD/DVD drive or does it have to be booted from one of those?

Comment: How you can boot a machine is a hardware support issue.  Your machine may be able to boot via PXE (refer https://askubuntu.com/questions/412574/pxe-boot-server-installation-steps-in-ubuntu-server-vm/414813) or other methods, but it's specific to your hardware.