# Automated PXE boot image selection and customized boot images

Tags: boot, networking, automation, pxe, initrd

## Details

I have a network of about 20 identical Dell PCs and 40 raspberry PI 3b+ units which were donated to a school where I'm currently doing some pro-bono work. The RPI units are for kids to browse a private intranet (learning utilities, educational games, etc.) and the PCs are for the older kids (different applications installed). **All of these machines are connected to the network via ethernet, and are on the same subnet.**

Since the school doesn't have much of a budget, and I can volunteer time (but I don't volunteer cash, as I'm not in a position to donate 20x new SSDs and 40x SD cards), I was planning to boot all these devices via PXE, since they don't actually require persistent storage.

---

## Question(s)

1. Is it possbile to, at boot time, run some sort of pre-execution environment (i.e. minimal Linux instance) that just queries the hardware to determine if it's a PC versus a Raspberry PI, and then boots/"chains" (i.e. [like those old "Ultimate Boot CD" images did](https://www.ultimatebootcd.com/)) another boot image (i.e. automatically detect hardware, and then proceed to boot a different OS image). **This would let me just create a pair of PXE images for all 60x computers.**
2. Are there any guides/tutorials on customizing Ubuntu/Debian/Raspian PXE images? I need to:

   - Add additional `apt-get` packages that are not included in the default Live USB/CD images.
   - Remove existing default `apt-get` packages that are not needed (to reduce the size of the OS, especially for the Raspberry PIs, which have very little RAM).
   - Deploy some custom static files (i.e. some config files and `udev` rules in `/etc`, some additional certificates in `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates`), and to run a one-time script when the system has finished booting (i.e. `sudo update-ca-certficates`, set a custom wallpaper, launch a browser, and run a few other tools).

---

## Work So Far

1. I haven't found much information at all on automatically detecting hardware type and dynamically providing a specific PXE boot image to the client machines. Beyond some articles that just recommend ["go with IPXE"](https://ipxe.org/), I couldn't find much help. **It looks like a powerful tool, but I can't determine from the documentation if it can launch one Linux instance, run a custom script to determine hardware type, and then load a separate boot image.**
2. Most of the article on StackOverflow (on this topic) are covering the topic of provisioning a PXE server and getting clients to connect to it. This I can do, **but my primary goal is editing the boot image that gets deployed** (i.e. `apt` packages present, adding/removing them as needed, adding extra static files in `/etc`, and having a customized script run once the OS has been brought up). [**I found an impressive looking tool for this, but sadly, it looks like it's been discontinued since Ubuntu 9.x series.**](https://sourceforge.net/projects/u-customizer/).

Answer (score 0):

- I expect Raspberry PI 3b+ having same network interface model so MAC having same Producer ID.

  1. Set DHCP server to subnet them based MAC partial-matching. Leave PC subnet the default/fallback. See `man dhcp.conf` for `isc-dhcp` server.
  2. Set separate PXE configuration for PC+Others/subnet and RP/subnet in TFTP server. Put a boot menu in each so end-user can force it, if it didn't get correct configuration. See [PXE Boot Server Installation Steps in Ubuntu Server VM](https://askubuntu.com/q/412574/26246)

  Those donated PC's may need setting an exception, either within DHCP or TFTP server.
- iPXE is for old net interfaces that don't support PXE. gPXE is to support other protocols than TFTP for faster file transfer like NFS,HTTP..etc
- For running some scripts after boot, check [How do I create a completely unattended install of Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/122505/26246) for kickstart and preseed. (Puppet may be an overkill)